# Can you set text and value of a TextboxFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

is it possible to set text and value of a textboxfor? if yes. how to do it dynamically?
Response is much appreciated.

Comment: What do `text` and `value` refer to? Do you want to set the text that is shown in the TextBox in the browser when the page is displayed?

Comment: Of course. But what do you mean _do it dynamically_?

Comment: @Markus yes the text that is shown in the view but when passed to the controller the value will enter.

Comment: @Stephen Meucke i want to pass the value and text from the controller to the textbox

Comment: Then show your model and view. If you have a model with a property say `Name` and you set the value of `"Renz"` in the controller, and pass the model to the view, then its `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)`

Comment: @Stephen Meucke but i want to set the text to name but i want the value to be Id

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Show some code so we can understand what your trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Id, new { Value = Model.name})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can by following way

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Id, new { @Value = "110"}) %>
```

Comment: i want the value to be a model variable

Comment: that is not possible with TextBoxFor...then go for TextBox only

Comment: can you please show me the format of textBox for that?